# Execution without OS

Tags: c, linux, boot, bootstrapping, bare-metal

How do you compile a **C** program in to a valid **ELF** format(or RAW format) so that it can be executed directly from RAM without any **OS**? Assume that a **bootloader** exists which is capable of loading the code to any location in RAM and start execution at that address. 
To be precise, what should be the compiler(**GCC**) flags? Is there a need for a map file?

A sample helloworld application would be most welcome :)

Just to elaborate my point,
let the main() method be an empty infinite while loop to ensure that no **OS** specific or standard library calls are used. The desired o/p is a hang. With the usual **GCC** options the bootloader would definitely fail to load the executable telling it is invalid **ELF** format. However by passing *-dN* option to the linker will make it a valid **ELF**. More compiler/linker options are required to make it hang and not crash!!  What exactly are those compiler options?

```
file.c:
int main()
{
    while(1);
}
```

Compilation
    gcc -c  -nostdinc -fno-builtin  file.c
    ld  -dN -nostdlib file.o

Bootloader loads **a.out** to RAM and executes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, there are limitations to what you can do, once bootloader finishes its work.
These limitations are because of following things:
(Assuming that your boot loader (eg: grub), takes you to 32-bit protected mode)
1. There is no paging enabled. You need to enable it.
2. There you cannot interact with devices as you have to set handlers for IRQ.

Here is a classic link which I used to learn the art of programming over bare metal(http://geezer.osdevbrasil.net/osd/index.htm).
Also, there is a download link on the page (http://geezer.osdevbrasil.net/osd/code/osd.tgz).
The tar file contains demo kernels with increasing level of complexity. 
Also, you can look into the make file (linux.mak), and get required flags for gcc.

I opened a random make file and found that following flags were used: 
gcc : -nostdinc -fno-builtin
ld: -nostdlib
(An explicit call to linker is made, hence ld also needs a flag).

The flags purpose is to tell gcc that there must be no linking done with the standard library.

Comment: Thanks...The links were very much useful :)

Answer (score 2):

coreboot can load stand-alone ELF.
see "Initializing DRAM":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreboot

Answer (score 1):

http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/index.php

This site answers your question step-by-step...

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that if you don't load an OS you must write a device driver to work with any device.  That means no writing to the screen without writing a driver for that particular video card, no reading from the disk without writing a driver for that particular hard drive controller card, no accessing the keyboard, etc.

You may want to look into something called [Kiosk Mode](http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+kiosk+mode) instead.  The basic idea is that the OS runs, loads everything need for your app, loads your app, and then you cannot switch to another app.

Comment: Instead of writing device drivers, you could just stay in real-mode and use BIOS interrupts to access all these things.  Otherwise, video (VESA), keyboard (PS/2 emulation), etc. is pretty standardized.

Comment: To begin with I was trying to create a Hang on the System( See code in the question). For producing a hang, you don't need any drivers (except may be memory driver which I think the boot-loader will provide) . But I was getting a crash. Once I am done with this I can get the driver code and explore further...